# inexplicable threading bevaviour

Tags: c#, multithreading

I can't make heads or tails of the following behaviour (please see comments in code)

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    string debugString = String.Concat("Inside Action ", i);
    Action newAction = new Action(() => { System.Console.WriteLine(debugString); });
    Task.Run(newAction);        // outputs: 0, 1, 2, 3 (not always exactly in this order, but this is understandable because of async execution)

    Action newAction2 = new Action(() => { System.Console.WriteLine("Inside Action2 " + i); });
    Task.Run(newAction2);        // outputs: 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 (...which is the value of i *after* the iteration, why?? "i" is a primitive int?!)
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

I don't understand the second behaviour. The variable i should be assigned to the Action as an Instance as the Action gets created. It looks like a pointer to i is created which has the value 1000 (last value of iteration) at the time the task is run...

Please explain. Thank you.

Comment: Should be `int inner = i; Action newAction2 = new Action(() => { System.Console.WriteLine("Inside Action2 " + inner); });`

Comment: FYI, I tried this in dotnetfiddle.net, and only saw this happening with the core 2.2 option. Roslyn and 4.7.x don't do this on that site.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I abused my ♦ powers to fix that for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example:

```cs
Action newAction2 = new Action(() => { System.Console.WriteLine("Inside Action2 " + i); });
```

the variable `i` is captured into the lambda. Not the *value* of `i`, but the **variable** `i`. That means that the *value* is whatever the loop happens to be at the moment that line of the task actually gets executed, **not** what it was when the task was created.

One lazy fix is to snapshot the value:

```cs
var tmp = i;
Action newAction2 = new Action(() => { System.Console.WriteLine("Inside Action2 " + tmp ); });
```

Importantly, the scope for "capture" purposes is defined by where the variable is **defined**. If we define `tmp` *inside* the loop, then that is the scope, hence: different `tmp` (semantically speaking) each loop iteration. However, in a `for` loop, the scope definition is technically *outside* the loop, hence why it is shared over all iterations.

Comment: The "snapshot" is what I did (unknowingly) with the first example where I used i in the string-building. Your answer is reproducable und well explained. Thank you. (Seams I have to learn more about lambda expressions)

Comment: P.S: this answer was so quick, that I can only mark it as correct in another 5 minutes ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have a typical *captured variable* scenario:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  ...
  Action newAction2 = new Action(() => { 
    System.Console.WriteLine("Inside Action2 " + i); });

  Task.Run(newAction2);
```

All threads use `i` variable from `for` loop. However, when threads have *started*, loop has *completed*, and thus `i == 1000`. That's why all the threads return `1000`.